# C# httpwebrequest cookies

Tags: c#

I'm using the below code to reuse the sessions.

Will I get the same session id on the grabUrl response cookies?

How do I know if both requests are using the same session/cookie?

Thanks.

```
CookieContainer cookCon = new CookieContainer();

Httpwebrequest loginReq = (httpwebrequest) loginReq.create(loginurl);

loginReq.cookiecontainer = cookCon;

... All the response stuffs

Httpwebrequest grabReq = (httpwebrequest) grabReq.create(grabUrl);

grabUrl.cookiecontainer = cookCon
```

When I add in below code to see the container contents, it shows that there is a session id:

```
        foreach (Cookie cook in cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(loginurl)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie_Get_Container:");
            Console.WriteLine("====================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", cook.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("====================================================");
        }
```

So I added cookies to the login response:

```
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(domainUrl), loginRes.Cookies);
```

I am not able to get the session id when I try to get from the cookieContainer.grabRes.Cookies.
Any advise?

Comment: I am 94% certain the answer is yes--but this is so trivial to test--why not just code it up, and see?

Comment: ... or inspect the outgoing request using Fiddler.

Comment: Any code to determine if they are using the same session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not showing code that grabs session cookie from first response I assume that you are not and the answer is "no, new session is created for second requset".

You want to get session ID (and other) from first response and set them on new requests (i.e. by adding them to the container).

Side note: depending on authenitcation method the information to authenticate the next requests (different from session ID) may not come in cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm quite new on this cookies thingy. Can you show me the code on how to add in to the container and where shld I place this code based on my code in the question. Thank you very much.